# Regex validation for grouping in Bash Scripting

Tags: regex, bash

I have tried creating a regex validation for Bash and have been doing this. It's working only for the first digit, the second one no. Can you help me out here?

```
while [[ $usrInput =~ [^[1-9]|[0-2]{1}$] ]]
do
        echo "This is not a valid option. Please type an integer between 1 and 12"
        read usrInput
done
```

Comment: You might want to validate your input without regex ... but in case: `^([1-9]|1[0-2])$`

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest ranges. You want something like

```
while ! [[ $usrInput =~ ^[0-9]|11|12$ ]]; do
```

although in general it would be simpler to compare a digit string numerically:

```
min=1
max=12
until [[ $usrInput =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] &&
      (( usrInput >= min && usrInput <= max )); do
```

Comment: I solved it by not using Regex at all using the -lt and the -gt. Apparently the regex is not the problem, but the symbols like =~.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you (or bash) are not grouping the expressions correctly. Either way, this'll work:

```
while read usrInput
do
  if [[ "$usrInput" =~ ^([1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]]
  then
      break
  else
    echo "Number not between 1 and 12"
  fi
done
```